# Django serializer update method key error in validated_data

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I m using django rest framework to provide api to multiple application. single models being shared with these applications. And every applications are using some fields that no other apps are using. I have to write update method on serializer and take action as per the fields value received from these apps. when i write the update method and in case django doesn't finds any key it throws error. let see the code:
Model:

```
class TaskChecker(models.Model):
    taskName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    notified = models.BooleanField (default=False)
    isDeleteRequest = models.BooleanField (default=False)
    isDeactivateMe = models.BooleanField (default=False)
    isActive = models.BooleanField (default=False)


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=TaskChecker
        fields='__all__'
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        isDeleteRequest = validated_data['isDeleteRequest']
        do some task
        isActive= validated_data['isActive']
        do some task
```

now the scenario is at a time either i will get validated_data['isDeleteRequest'] or validated_data['isActive']. in that case i get key error. how to resolve the issue? if i dont get the key at that time i should not get error. please help. thank you so much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TaskSerializer use the dict get method instead.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=TaskChecker
        fields='__all__'
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        isDeleteRequest = validated_data.get('isDeleteRequest', False)
        do some task
        isActive= validated_data.get('isActive', False)
        do some task
```

Comment: using validated_data.get('isDeleteRequest', False) instead of validated_date['isDeleteRequest'] works